# tar: /dev/st0: Cannot write: Input/output error

Tags: rhel, tar, tape

When we attempt to use tar to write data to an LTO-5 tape, we get the following error. The device starts to write, and then fails. See the tar command and output, followed by the dmesg output. I included the mt status as well. Any help is appreciated.

This is an Ultrium 3280 LTO5 drive connected through a SAS interface on RHEL 6. We tried a second drive, and second tape. These are brand new tapes, and new drives.

Both of the following commands run without any issues.

```
sudo mt -f /dev/st0 stsetoptions scsi2logical
sudo mt -f /dev/st0 erase
```

`mt status` provides the following

```
sudo mt -f /dev/st0 status
SCSI 2 tape drive: File number=0, block number=0, partition=0.
Tape block size 0 bytes.
Density code 0x58 (no translation).
Soft error count since last status=0
General status bits on (41010000): BOT ONLINE IM_REP_EN
```

When we attempt to write some output to the drive, we get the following. The device acts as if it is writing, lights start flashing and starts making noise.

```
sudo tar cvf /dev/st0 /vader
tar: Removing leading `/' from member names
/vader/
/vader/data0905a-data0906/
/vader/data0905a-data0906/data0905a-FINAL/
/vader/data0905a-data0906/data0905a-FINAL/data0905a.trk
/vader/data0905a-data0906/data0905a-FINAL/plots/
/vader/data0905a-data0906/data0905a-FINAL/plots/0905A_trak.ps
/vader/data0905a-data0906/data0905a-FINAL/plots/0905A_trak.jpg
/vader/data0905a-data0906/data0905a-FINAL/das/
/vader/data0905a-data0906/data0905a-FINAL/das/uw/
/vader/data0905a-data0906/data0905a-FINAL/das/uw/0905tmp.tar
/vader/data0905a-data0906/data0905a-FINAL/das/uw/0905nud.tar
/vader/data0905a-data0906/data0905a-FINAL/das/uw/0905das.tar
/vader/data0905a-data0906/data0905a-FINAL/das/uw/0905wnc.tar
/vader/data0905a-data0906/data0905a-FINAL/das/uw/0905bdp.tar
/vader/data0905a-data0906/data0905a-FINAL/das/uw/0905vp1.tar
/vader/data0905a-data0906/data0905a-FINAL/das/uw/0905rv1.tar
/vader/data0905a-data0906/data0905a-FINAL/das/uw/0905tsg.tar
/vader/data0905a-data0906/data0905a-FINAL/das/uw/0905co2.tar
/vader/data0905a-data0906/data0905a-FINAL/das/uw/0905guv.tar
/vader/data0905a-data0906/data0905a-FINAL/das/uw/0905ng1.tar
/vader/data0905a-data0906/data0905a-FINAL/das/uw/0905wx1.tar
/vader/data0905a-data0906/data0905a-FINAL/dcp/
/vader/data0905a-data0906/data0905a-FINAL/dcp/0905dcp.tar
tar: /dev/st0: Cannot write: Input/output error
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

Here is `dmesg`

```
mptbase: ioc0: LogInfo(0x31120403): Originator={PL}, Code={Abort},
SubCode(0x0403) cb_idx mptscsih_io_done
LSI Debug log info 31120403 for channel 0 id 2
st0: Error 80000 (driver bt 0x0, host bt 0x8).
```

Does anyone have any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: A shot into the dark: Check the manual for the blocksize the drive expects and do a test write with exactly a multiple of that size (or tell tar to use that blocksize).

Comment: Hi, welcome to unix.SE.  I see you had good intentions with your attempts to format your question clearly.  However, your implementation was off-target.  I've gone through and made some improvements.  Click "edit" to see how code blocks should be formatted on Stack Exchange.

Comment: A web search found http://forums.opensuse.org/showthread.php/451165-LTO-4-drive-disappears-after-using-tar-and-I-O-error . Suggested fix is as @yeti said: increase the blocking factor. try `sudo tar cvbf 1024 /dev/st0 /vader`

Comment: We're going to try using a blocking factor of 1024. Thanks for the suggestions. I'll get the output as soon as I can.

Comment: Ping? It is ok now?

Comment: Unfortunately we've had other issues that have kept us from working on this. I will update as soon as I can.

I was also out of town for the last 4 days.

Answer (score 1):

I've mostly seen this with faulty tape drives (to the point of suspecting the tape first and shipping a unit to an analysis lab), however the other commentators are right in that blocksize matters. There are certainly cases where you need to even increase the `buffer_kbs` parameter of the `st` module to correctly write to tape.

I don't have a tape drive anymore, but you can use the `sg3_utils` to query the drive, and one of the fields there IIRC contained block size information.